# PHP array / preg_replace by position

Tags: php, arrays, replace, position

I have a body of text that includes randomised numbers.

I make an array of the numbers, process them (look up relevant information to display based on each number) and then reinsert the changed array into the original text at the same locations I took the array from.

So far I am using preg_match_all to create the new array, then foreach for the process, then I  insert these strings into a new array called $replacement.

So I have an array that I want to use to replace the strings in the original text. The problem is that I want the replacement calculated on the position value - regardless of what's in the array, string 1 matches string 1 by position in the array.

Difficult to explain. Here's an example.

`Original text: Hello 1 Hello 2 Hello 3`

```
original array {
    [0] 1
    [1] 2
    [2] 3
}
replacement array {
    [0] One
    [1] Two
    [2] Three
}
```

So when I do what I need to do, the original body text would look like:

`Hello One Hello Two Hello Three`

The catch is, I'd also want it to look like `Hello One Hello Two Hello Three` even if the original array was:

```
original array {
    [0] 1
    [1] 1
    [2] 1
}
replacement array {
    [0] One
    [1] Two
    [2] Three
}
```

How could I do that?

Comment: in second case what is the criteria for replacing ?

Comment: Location of each string.

Comment: So basically you dont want your "original array" it all depends on second array (replacement array) and its key rite ?

Comment: Pretty much! I only care about the positions of the original strings for the final replacement - other processing already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying this :-

```
$original_array=array(1,2,3);
foreach($original_array as $key=>$value) {
  echo str_replace($key, 'Hello',$key);
}
```

output:-  HelloHelloHello

Answer (score 0):

Is this one you looking for...???

```
$string="Hello 1 Hello 2 Hello 3";
    $rslt=preg_match_all('/(\d)/',$string,$matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $key=>$value){
        $digit= $key+1;
        $words=convertToWord($digit);
        $string= str_replace($value,$words,$string);
    }

echo $string;
function convertToWord($digit)
    {
        switch($digit)
        {
            case "0": return "zero";
            case "1": return "one";
            case "2": return "two";
            case "3": return "three";
            case "4": return "four";
            case "5": return "five";
            case "6": return "six";
            case "7": return "seven";
            case "8": return "eight";
            case "9": return "nine";
            case "": return "only";
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Hello one Hello two Hello three

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZUnTDd)